# SFINAE перегрузка по сигнатуре Callable-объекта

Tags: c++

Ребята, помогите написать перегруженную функцию, которая принимает на вход произвольный Callable объект:

```
template<typename Callable>
/* ... */ foo(Callable &&callable)
{
}
```

И делает следующие действия:

Для первой перегрузки : Если переданный объект может быть вызван от одного `std::string` (т.е. если конструкция `std::declval<Callable>()(std::declval<std::string>())` валидна), то тип возвращаемого значения `foo` должен быть выведен как *тип возвращаемого значения Сallable*(std::string), т.е. `decltype(std::declval<Callable>()(std::declval<std::string>()))(std::string)`. Например, если объект может быть вызван от одного `std::string` и в результате такого вызова возвращает `double`, то тип возвращаемого значения `foo` должен быть `double(std::string)`. Если переданный объект не может быть вызван от одного `std::string`, то по принципу SFINAE эта перегрузка `foo` должна отброситься.

Для второй перегрузки : Аналогично, только теперь вместо `std::string` - `int`

Говоря простыми словами, мне нужно проверить, можно ли вызвать переданный Callable-объект от одного `std::string`, и, если да, то вывести "сигнатуру" этого объекта. Если нельзя, то проверить то же самое для одного `int`

Очень желательно без C++17

Comment: Вроде надо static_assert и enable_if_t  как-то применить, но мозг отказвает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде не так уж и сложно:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Callable> auto
foo(Callable && callable) -> decltype(::std::declval<Callable>()(::std::declval<::std::string>()))
{
    ::std::cout << "string" << ::std::endl;
    return callable(::std::string{});
}

template<typename Callable> auto
foo(Callable && callable) -> decltype(::std::declval<Callable>()(::std::declval<int>()))
{
    ::std::cout << "int" << ::std::endl;
    return callable(int{});
}

int main()
{
    ::std::cout << foo([](::std::string) { return "test"; }) << ::std::endl;
    ::std::cout << foo([](int) { return 42; }) << ::std::endl;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JqGHvyrKNpOxIuS8)